# Log transformation to get normal distribution. Applicable for a Lab study?

Tags: statistics, normalization, review, soil

I did a lab incubation study on nitrous oxide and carbon dioxide emission from different soils. the data are highly skewed. I log transformed the data to run anova. But one of my coworker is really doubtful about that as we haven't found any paper on soil incubation study where researchers used log transformed data. What should I do? Should I log transform my data to get a normal distribution no matter what others do? Our concern is about the reviewers' questions when we submit the article to a journal.

Comment: You'll get more interest in this question on stats.stackexchange.com.